# Why am I receiving ActionView::Template::Error No route matches for my AJAX toggle button? Rails 5.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I created a share button with AJAX, that changes state and count when a user clicks on it. The AJAX button is inside of a partial called **_share.html.erb**, I invoke the partial inside of the each block for all posts and individual post. I created a supporting **share.js.erb** that swaps the buttons inside of the partial when either is clicked. I have two actions in the post controller **share[POST]**/**unshare[DESTROY]**. How can I correctly configure my AJAX toggle-button to properly render and change state?

I tried changing the variables being passed to the view to instance variables in the share.js.erb and **_share_post_btn.html.erb** partial. I also the made changes to the actions in the controller. I still receive no route matches unshare when I click the button.

**Error Below:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"unshare", :controller=>"posts", :id=>#<Post id: nil, body_text: nil, photo: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, post_id: nil, original_post_id: 0, posts_counter: 0, cached_votes_total: 0, cached_votes_score: 0, cached_votes_up: 0, cached_votes_down: 0, cached_weighted_score: 0, cached_weighted_total: 0, cached_weighted_average: 0.0, impressions_count: nil, hash_id: nil, posts_count: nil>, :on=>:collection}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]):
1: <li id="#share_<%= @post.id %>">
2:   <% if current_user.shared?(@post) %>
3:     <%= link_to unshare_post_path(@post), method: :destroy, remote: true, style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>
4:       <i class="fas fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color"></i>
5:     <% end %>
6:   <% else %>
```

**UPDATE 1: ERROR 2 WITHOUT PARTIAL**

```
Started POST "/posts/6/share" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-09 13:09:46 -0500
Processing by PostsController#share as JS
  Parameters: {"on"=>:collection, "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (7.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   Post Load (18.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."hash_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["hash_id", "6"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (5.0ms)  BEGIN
  Post Exists (4.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."hash_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["hash_id", "Lbwmxf2zvU9S"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Create (50.0ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "original_post_id", "hash_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2019-02-09 18:09:47.987106"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-09 18:09:47.987106"], ["original_post_id", 6], ["hash_id", "Lbwmxf2zvU9S"]]
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Update All (2.0ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "posts_count" = COALESCE("posts_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 6]]
  (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3666ms (ActiveRecord: 93.9ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass):

app/models/mention.rb:14:in `create_from_text'
app/models/post.rb:33:in `add_mentions'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:60:in `share'
Processing by ExceptionHandler::ExceptionsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"on"=>:collection, "id"=>"6"}
Error during failsafe response: Could not render layout: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :posts, on: :collection do
    member do
      post :share
      delete :unshare
    end
  end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def share
  @post = current_user.posts.new(original_post_id: @post.id)
  if @post.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
      format.js {render action: "share"}
    end
  end
end

def unshare
  @post = current_user.posts.find(original_post_id: @post.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.destroy
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
      format.js {render action: "unshare"}
    end
  end
end
```

**share.js.erb**

```
 $('#share_<%= @post.id%>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "posts/share", :locals => {:post => @post}) %>');
```

**unshare.js.erb**

```
$('#share_<%= @post.id%>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "posts/share", :locals => {:post => @post}) %>');
```

**_share.html.erb**

```
<li id="#share_<%= @post.id %>">
  <% if current_user.shared?(@post) %>
    <%= link_to unshare_post_path(@post), method: :destroy, remote: true, style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>
  <i class="fas fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color"></i>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to share_post_path(@post.id), method: :post, remote: true, style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>
  <i class="far fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color"></i>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</li>
<li id="#share_count-<%= @post.id %>">
  <small class="text-muted"><%= @post.posts_count ? number_to_human(@post.posts_count, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => {:thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B'}) : 0 %></small>
</li>
```

**posts/_posts.html.erb**

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post_container">
     <%= render 'share', locale: post %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

**Expected Results**: The share button should change state and the posts_count should increment/deincrement.

**Actual Results**: I receive an ActionViewTemplate::Error Stating that no route matches unshare with all nil values for Post object.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently rendering the `_share` partial in the `_posts` partial by sending

```
<%= render 'share', locale: post %>
```

To have the current post object available in the template you need to alter that to

```
<%= render 'share', locals: { post: post } %>
```

as [the documentation states](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html). The current method call is just providing a useless and unprocessed parameter called `locale`.

In the rendered partial, the local variable will then be available as `post` (without `@`).

The `_share` partial is probably using some instance variable defined elsewhere which has just been initialized but it is definitely not using the local variable you provide in `_posts`.

Comment: I solved this problem by moving iterator into the index page and rendering conditional partials. Actually, it didn't completely fix the ajax button. But, the problem that I'm addressing here. Is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The view was double rendering the post. As a result, I moved the views into separate partials.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <%= render partial: "posts/#{post.post_type}", locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```